# What happens when we do (char *) casting to store integer data into char pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, pointer-arithmetic

```
int a;
(&a+1) -&a: 1
(char*)(&a+1) -(char*)&a: 4
```

Could you please explain why we got a different result when we did `(char *)` casting?

I compiled the code and found that the addresses are the same before and after casting. But when we do arithmetic, we get different results. Why?

```
&a: 1283454684
&a+1: 1283454688
(char*)&a: 1283454684
(char*)(&a+1): 1283454688
```

Comment: Ironically, the answer to this question is [in the tag info itself](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pointer-arithmetic/info) for the pointer-arithmetic tag.

Answer (score 0):

When doing pointer arithmetic the C compiler uses the size of the data pointed by the pointer as the "unit of measure", given that the smallest size is a single byte.

So when you have a pointer `type* p` and you add `n` the compiler will do:

```
C: 
   p+n

ASM: 
   p + n * sizeof(<data type pointed by p>)
```

Note that this happens under the hood everytime you access an array.

```
struct bigStruct{
   int a;
   int b;
   ...
   int z;
};

// Define array of 100 bigStructs
struct bigStruct allStructs[100];

allStructs[3] == *(&allStructs + 3)
allStructs[3] == *(&struct bigStruct)((char*)&allStructs + 3*sizeof(struct bigStruct))
```